# About literal objects and, perhaps, auto executable functions

Tags: javascript

```
var a = {
    b: {
        c: 1
    },
    d: this.b.c
};
```

Error:

```
this.b is undefined
```

How can I call b.c?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Self-references in object literal declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var a = {
    b: {
        c: 1
    }
};
a.d = a.b.c;
```

Would be the only way. `this.b.c` is executed in the scope where you're constructing the `a` object, rather than within the object itself; therefore `this` is equal to `window`, and `window.b == undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Although [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/444991/matt) told you there was only one way, this may be an alternative:

```
var a = {
  b: {c: 1},
  d: function(){return this.b.c;}
}
alert(a.d()); //=> 1
```

or

```
var a = {
  b: {c: 1},
  d: function(){if (this.d instanceof Function) {this.d = this.b.c;}}
}
a.d();
alert(a.d); //=> 1
```

or execute an anonymous function:

```
var a = function(){
      var obj ={b: {c: 1}}
      obj.d = obj.b.c;
      return obj;
}();
alert(a.d); //=> 1
```